# Hibernate one to one mapping using only foreign id

Tags: java, sql, hibernate

Given we have

> tables Person (id, address_id) and Address
>   (id, town)

and POJO

> class Person {
>
> ```
>  int id;
>  int addressId;
> ```
>
> }
>
> class Address{
>           int id;
>       String  town;
>
> }

Is is possible to map an address to a person? (Hibernate)

*Querying a Person will only get it's id and it's address id

Is it also possible to search a person by his/her town?

**UPDATE:**
I'd like to add: the Person class is restricted to use only `int addressId;`
One reason would be that we want the Person class to be atomic (all data is independent) and use it for web services or the like

thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace the `private int addressId;` field in the Person by the field `private Address address;`,  and add a `@OneToOne` annotation to the field.

```
@Entity
class Person {
  @Id
  int id;

  @OneToOne
  Address address;
}

@Entity
class Address{
   @Id
   int id;

   String town;
}
```

*If Address is not an own table, then have a loot at the @Embeddable Annotation. (Example in [Chapter 2.2.2.2. Access type](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.5/reference/en/html_single/#entity-mapping-property) of Hibernate Annotation Reference)*

---

Update:

> I'd like to add: the Person class is restricted to use only int addressId;

you need a more complex HQL Query: see [Hibernate Reference Documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-subqueries)

```
SELECT p FROM Person as p
WHERE p.addressId in (
    SELECT a.id FROM Address AS a WHERE a.town = 'Dresden'
)
```

Comment: @thirdy: I have extended my answer

Answer (score 0):

First of all... int istn't al really good choice here as ids can be null (as long as they're not persited and get their value as @GeneratedValue and storing the addressId is cumbersome...
What about

```
class Person {
    Integer id;
    Address address;
}
```

Then you could query "SELECT p.id, p.address.id FROM Person p" and "SELECT p FROM Person p WHERE p.address.town = :town"...